# Equal Network Partitioning in Byzantine Problem with 2 generals

Tags: distributed-system, consensus

Assuming the typical byzantine setup with generals and lieutenants, communication is binary(attack/retreat) and the graph of communication is complete.

Assuming that the maximum number of faulty people can be 3, which implies (for an asynchronous system) that there should be a minimum of 10 (3 x 3 + 1) total (generals + lieutenants).

What if there are two generals: the first one is faulty and sending 'attack' and the other good general is sending'retreat'?

How does consensus get reached in this case since the number of people is even, so every person will receive the same number of messages of attack and retreat?

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

Property: The system is said to resist Byzantine faults if a component A can broadcast a value x, and then:

1. If A is honest, then all honest components agree on the value x.
2. In any case, all honest components agree on the same value y.

It is ok if they all don't reach any agreement. The constrain is, if a value is chosen, it needs to meet the above requirements. All agree to a value that was broadcasted by a component (honest to otherwise), and they don't choose a value that was never broadcasted by anyone, out of thin air.  Also, if no value is chosen it is all good but in case a value is chosen it needs to be the same for all honest components.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to see how either of these two conditions are satisfying, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes, neither of them are satisfying so "It is ok if they all don't reach any agreement." Wrong agreement is bad, no agreement is ok.

Comment: Correct if I am wrong, wasn't the desired end goal for byzantine agreement was all general attack or retaliate? (Irrespective of what is "correct"?)

Comment: No, the goal is if they reach agreement, they all do the same thing. If they don't reach agreement a pre-assigned default strategy can be used. As long as they know they didn't reach agreement:

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault

Comment: But there is a condition that in order to reach consensus in a network with F faulty nodes, there must be at least 3f+1 nodes, but here that condition is being satisfied, right?